# Location client's priority against setInterval,setFastestInterval and setSmallestDisplacement?

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

If

```
locationClient.setInterval(60*1000);  
locationClient.setSmallesDisplacement(10);       
locationClient.setFastestInterval(1000);
```

is given, then when will the updates be called? If user have moved 10mts within 60secs, will location updates be called? Or if user haven't moved any distance within 60secs can the updates be fetched? If all the properties are used at once which will be given priority?

I have used all of them in my app. But, it worked well only when displacement is 1mt and interval is 30secs. And got more weird results when displacement is increased to 20mts keeping interval same.

Answer (score 2):

With `10m` displacement and `60 sec interval` and no `fastestInterval` value. Google Play Location Services will try fetch location every `60 sec`, see if it was 10m, if yes it will call `onLocationChanged` otherwise it will discard that value.

Now with `fastestInterval = 1`, if it will have a location value in `1 sec` and if displacement is more than `10m` then you will receive location in `onLocationChanged`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation like you. I wonder Interval will be call first to be able determine the displacement or the displacement will trigger first.

If User travel 5 meter in your case then travel back to original location 5meter then will locationcleint update newlocation or it wont since user stay at the same location but traveled 10 meter